# How to start with material design

Tags: android, layout, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to create a beautiful layout, I've found an example but it's not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="56dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"/>

    <!-- Email Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:hint="@string/email_str" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Password Label -->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/et_contraseña"
            android:hint="@string/contraseña_str" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/but_iniciar_sesion"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/iniciar_sesion_str"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/but_crear_cuenta"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="@string/crear_cuenta_str"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It is giving me this message error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

For sure, I have to import a library or something like that. 
Maybe add some lines in gradle or AndroidManifest.xml

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependencies to your local gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0"
    compile "com.android.support:design:25.1.0"
}
```

Otherwise, if u'll have trouble "Error inflating.." try to clean and rebuild project.
P.S. Activity that uses those layout should extend AppCompatActivity instead of Activity

Comment: I did it and I am still receiving the same error message. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sergio hmm, I see an interesting symbol in android:id and android:hint, try to rename them

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above answer concerning adding the dependencies, I beleive you must also set the theme on the TextInputLayouts using:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```

Here is an example using your code:

```
<!-- Email Label -->
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:hint="@string/email_str" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```